# Capture stored procedure output with python pyodbc

Tags: python, stored-procedures, output, teradata, pyodbc

I have a stored procedure which I am calling using Python scripts and Pyodbc module. The code looks like this:

```
import pyodbc
pyodbc.pooling=False
oConnexion = pyodbc.connect("driver={Teradata};dbcname=myServer;DefaultDatabase=myDB;uid=myUser;pwd=myPassword;charset=utf8;", autocommit=True)
oConnexion.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='utf-8')
oConnexion.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WCHAR, encoding='utf-8')
oConnexion.setencoding(encoding='utf-8')
oCursor = oConnexion.cursor()
oQueryRegisterBatch = "CALL DEV_AUDIT.SP_AUDIT_BATCH('ED_DATA_QUALITY_MANUAL', 'REGISTER', '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000000', '2999-12-31 00:00:00.000000');"
oCursor.execute(oQueryRegisterBatch)
for row in oCursor:
    print (row)
```

The stored procedure creates a new record and returns the record id (BATCH_KEY). When I execute the stored procedure in Teradata, it returns the BATCH_KEY properly but I am not able to capture it in Python. I get the following error message instead of the value:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: No results.  Previous SQL was not a query.
```

I could retrieve the BATCH_KEY by querying on the table after calling the stored procedure but I would like to avoid. Could you please advise how to capture the output of the stored procedure?

Thanks

Comment: The pyodbc Wiki page [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Calling-Stored-Procedures) shows how to do it for SQL Server using an anonymous code block. Perhaps a similar approach could be used for Teradata by tweaking the SQL syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the documentation of pyodbc package, it is not possible to capture the output of a stored procedure. This is documented here: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Calling-Stored-Procedures

> pyodbc does not currently implement the optional .callproc method.

There is a workaround which could work depending on your database engine which is to embed the call to a stored procedure into a query.

> Because pyodbc does not have .callproc we need to use a workaround for
>   retrieving the values of output parameters and return values. The
>   specific method will depend on what your particular ODBC driver
>   supports, but for Microsoft's ODBC drivers for SQL Server we can use
>   an "anonymous code block" to EXEC the stored procedure and then SELECT
>   the output parameters and/or return values.

See details in the link above.